# Setting the color of a cell using ExcelPackage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excelpackage

I am using vb.net and I have an asp.net application where I use [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/). I wanted to know how to set the background color of a particular cell or a row of cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use the component Epplus, it is quite complete and need not be installed on production server.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but here is the answer:

```
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Example");
string index= "A1";
ws.Cells[index].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;    
ws.Cells[index].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
```

Please note that you must set the PatternType before you can set a background color or an exception is thrown.

Sorry but my example is c#, you will need to convert to VB.Net to be 100% correct for the question!

Comment: It seems you can also use a range: `ws.Cells["A1:B7"]`.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156118/how-to-set-color-or-background-with-excelpackage#17157666.