# How to set color or background with "excelpackage"

Tags: c#, excel, excelpackage

I use this package: [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) though I can't figure out how to set the background color for the cell. I tried to use this:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
```

But it shows that the properties are not found.

[image]

Sounds like I should use something similar to this:

```
worksheet.Cell(5, columnIndex + 1).Style = "background-color: red";
```

But I am not sure how it works and I couldn't find the tutorial for it. Please help.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try something along these lines (Taken from the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) sample files provided):

```
using (var range = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 5]) 
    {
        range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.DarkBlue);
    }
```

Comment: @SharpC The numbers represent a range: (FromRow, FromCol, ToRow, ToCol).

Answer (score 0):

For `ExcelPackage`

```
workSheet.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.LightTrellis;
workSheet.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightSeaGreen);
var allCells = workSheet.Cells["A1:B1"];
var cellFont = allCells.Style.Font;
```